# Running debug in VSCode brings up "rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error"

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Why am I getting this error?

```
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\vscodevim.vim\.registers'
extensionHostProcess.js:147
stack trace: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\vscodevim.vim\.registers'
```

Everything was working last night when I shut things down. The only change I made was I ran a Firestore upgrade but the app worked after that.

Now, everytime I try to run the code a new instance of VSCode comes up with the title, "Extension Development Host Search" and I get the above error in the debug console of the vscode where I started the debug session.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It turns out I had the index.js file open when I was trying to debug my code.

I switched to one of the app files and everything worked fine.

Sorry for the post.